# What exactly does a ChannelFaultEvent signify in Flex/BlazeDS?

Tags: apache-flex, air, blazeds

I have a Flex with BlazeDS application which uses streaming AMF. We see sometimes in production that we get a `ChannelFaultEvent.FAULT`. After that sometimes, we get a `ChannelEvent.CONNECT` for some of our `Consumer` objects, but not for all of them.

What exactly does this event signify? There seems to be a `reconnecting` property as well on this event. What does that mean when true or false ?

Can we be sure that if the `reconnecting` property is true, a reconnect will be done? Or is that only saying that it might try to reconnect? Will we get an event if that reconnect fails?

Comment: It seems like you're asking us to determine the business logic that your app should run on; as opposed to the answer to a specific programming question.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I beg to differ. I seek information on what the ChannelFaultEvent really represents and what the reconnecting property  exactly means

Comment: Perhaps you should make your question more clear. Phrasing such as "What is a good way to..." and "would it be okay to..." are not specific; but make it seem like you want a discussion of options.  This site is best for answers to specific programming questions.